# how to run multiple functions and then a callback

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Once again I am 'dabbling' in the dark art of javascript and jQuery without much of a clue as to what I'm actually doing. All I know is that I managed to get my code to function by cribbing bits of other code and modifying it a bit, and after a lot of cursing, it worked.... in a fashion.

Below is a piece of my code, which correctly builds and displays a dynamic selectbox with values returned from a mysql query. When the user selects one of the items from the list, the code successfully runs a function which displays a map associated with that item.

What I ACTUALLY need it to do is also run the code to display the map for the default/top item returned by the query first, and THEN whenever a new item is selected it should run the function to display the newly selected map.

I hope the explanation has been clear enough, but feel free to chastise me if not.

Many thanks,

Rob.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#selecthere').load('/temp/php_script.php?r='+ random, function () 
 { //callback
$('select', this).change(function () { //catch onchange event of select
//call your function here, pass the selected value
initialize($(this).val());
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited in light of comments below.)

If I understand, `initialize(val)` is the function that draws the map associated with `val`, and you want to run it when the page loads with `val` being whatever is in the select box by default. To do this, you could just add the function call in your `ready` function as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var random = Math.random();
    // load contents of php script into #selecthere element
    $('#selecthere').load('/temp/php_script.php?r='+ random, function (){ 
       // the contents of the php script are now loaded
       // go ahead and call initialize() on the value that is selected by default
       initialize($('select[name=title]').val());
       // attach a function to fire when select element is changed
       $('select[name=title]').change(function () { 
           // here 'this' refers to the select element
           // call initialize() with the value of select element
           initialize($(this).val());
       });
    });
});
```

Hope I understood.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand (and again, excuse my vagueness - I really don't understand it myself). below is the php that it calls, and currently, once it's called the php it is able to build the select box, and then when someone picks an item from the list, the .change then calls the initialize($(this).val()); which builds the new map. Your code almost seems to work, it displays a map, but it doesn't seem to pass any value to it.

Comment: ` echo "<select class=\"selectbox\" name=\"title\" value='' tabindex=\"2\"></option>";
// printing the list box select command

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $row
$selected = ( $id == $row['id'] ) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; 
$section_select .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . $row['title'] . '</option>';  
}
echo $section_select; `

Comment: ...not quite, it's the id that it uses to build the map, not the actual displayed title. I tried just substituting title for id in your code, but that didn't do it either. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: ...ignore me - changing the title for id does work - I just had to take out the     `var random = Math.rand();` bit as it was already declared a couple of lines above. I think it works perfectly - just checking but BIG thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JQuery Events API](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). This way you can run functions when different user interactions takes place. Small example:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

This will run when a item with the id #foo is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but Doug Owings seems to have understood my ramblings better.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got the help you needed even if it wasn't from me :)